# How to add Imageview in another Fragment Activity after get data from JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I have an android application run with TabHost. I would like to update and add the image view in another fragment activity once the JSON data is obtained in MainActivity. But when I called shp.AddImages() in MainActivity class, the application crash. Please help~~

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {

    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private TabHost mTabHost;

    private String server_url = "http://comicking.blob.core.windows.net/xml/testing.json";

    private JSONHandler obj;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    ArrayList<Book> bookList;

    BookAdapter bookadapter;



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        InitialiseTabHost();

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());             

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);

        new JSONAsyncTask().execute(server_url);

        bookadapter = new BookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, bookList);

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.AddImages(bookList);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Refresh:
                //openSearch();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    // Method to add a TabHost
    private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec) {

        tabSpec.setContent(new MyTabFactory(activity));

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    }
    // Manages the Tab changes, synchronizing it with Pages
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {

        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();

        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }

    // Manages the Page changes, synchronizing it with Tabs

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

        this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

    }

    private void InitialiseTabHost() {

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup();

        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("Home"));

        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Shop").setIndicator("Shop"));

        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Collection").setIndicator("Collection"));

        MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Help").setIndicator("Help"));

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }
```

**Asynctask class**

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("book");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Book book = new Book();

                        book.setName(object.getString("name"));
                        book.setImage(object.getString("img"));

                        bookList.add(book);
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            //bookadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class Shop extends Fragment {

    public Map<String,Book> shoplist = new HashMap<String,Book>();
    private View rootView;
    private LinearLayout shopLL;
    private Context c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop, container, false);
        shopLL = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopLinearLayout);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void AddImages(ArrayList<Book> booklist){

        c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        for(int i = 0; i < booklist.size(); i++){

            ImageView img= new ImageView(c);
            shopLL.addView(img);

        }

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Shop.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/shopLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to update image in `Shop` from `MainActivity` ?

Comment: I want to instantiate a new ImageView and add into the scrollview's linear layout.

Comment: Can you please tell me what content you have in MyTabFactory?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your layout xml? Assuming that you have "Shop", fragment defined in the layout file, you can get reference to that fragment by id. You can then call the method on Shop fragment class with the returned list.

Comment: I updated the question with Shop.xml. Can show me how to set reference for it?

Comment: Is this what you mean?`Shop shopFrag = (Shop)
              getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Shop);`

Comment: but I don't have <Fragment></Fragment> in my activity_main.xml. Is there any alternative way to do it? (just update question with activity_main.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask is a backend services u r using, u may return a object instead of boolean

Modified of JSONAsyncTask :-

```
//**** e.g.
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    // define a caller
    Shop caller;

    //create a Constructor for caller;
    public JSONAsyncTask (Shop caller) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         this.caller = caller;
    }

    ///&& method doInBackground
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
          .....


         //custom your returning jsonObject 
         return jsonobject;
    }

    ////&& return jsonobject back to ur fragment class here by pass in caller
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        caller.onBackgroundTaskCompleted(jsonObject);
    }

}
```

in your shift the MainActivity class  method to Shop fragment class get ur json object:-

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
           new JSONAsyncTask().execute(server_url);
    }


//your returning result
public void onBackgroundTaskCompleted(JSONObject result) {
        Log.i("TAG", result:"+result);

        if(result!=null){
            //process your result to get the booklist here

            Booklist booklist;


           addimage(booklist);


         }

}
```

Gd Luck :)

Comment: Thank you for answer. New knowledge for me : ) . But my application crash once I called the AddImages() in MainActvity. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: im not sure when u call the add image? but after review your source, you may wait the response only called fragment,

Comment: fyi, your current app crash is due to your booklist object is null, may log it out to double confirm